# How to support someone with a budding interest in genealogy?

Tags: discussion, editing, specific-question

This question: [How to support someone with a budding interest in genealogy?](https://genealogy.stackexchange.com/questions/3784/gift-for-mom-something-genealogy-related) has been placed on hold. In its current form it is geared towards being a shopping and list question. These are troublesome as they can be highly subjective and may lead to long strings (lists) of low quality answers. All of which may all be equally valid. This site aims to provide high quality, definitive answers.

Could this question be saved by editing it to read...
 **How to support someone with a budding interest in genealogy?**

I see this to be closer along the lines of this question, which seeks advice on dealing with an aging gen. society. [Working with an aging genealogy society?](https://genealogy.stackexchange.com/questions/2298/working-with-an-aging-genealogy-society) A question seeking advice, but hopefully drawing closer to a single, well-thought-out answer.

Comment: I'm much happier with this than the original question. Maybe "How to encourage..." rather than "How to support..."

Comment: Yes, but I think we also need to be aware that there is a grey line between fixing a post and giving it a complete makeover.

Comment: I also fear this new proposed question is so vague and unspecific, it will hardly be a help to anyone. However, this is also dependent on the quality of the answer(s).

Comment: Yes, a good answer would supply advice that the OP is seeking to aid in assisting/affirming his mom in her pursuit of genealogy (some family historians are teased, ridiculed or even threatened by their family members instead of supported by them). A good answer would also be a reference to others on how to encourage others to expand, improve, move along an interest.

Comment: @AmericanLuke, so CGS asks the new question and comments in the old one to point to the new? ALthough makoever is better than closure and deletion which is what this one faces...